# form_for mixing id and locale parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for, globalize3

I'm trying to get Globalize3 working on my app. I have the toy projet of blog posts, that I want to translate.

My urls look like this : `localhost/en/posts` `localhost/fr/posts`

Here's how I do it in my `ApplicationController`

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] if params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

I'm using the same `form_for` for creating and updating posts. Here's the view code :

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

It works fine for when I go to the `/new` page, here's the controller code:

```
def new                                    
  @post = Post.new                         
end   

def create                                 
  @post = Post.new(post_params)            

  if @post.save                            
    redirect_to action: :show, id: @post.id
  else                                     
    render 'new'                           
  end                                      
end
```

But when I try to edit a post with the url `/en/posts/1/edit`, it mixes the parameters passed to the `form_for`. That's the error message:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :locale=>#, :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:locale, :id]

My question is : why does it do that and how can I fix thix?

---

I've already tried some things like changing the `form_for` declaration to this:

`<%= form_for(@post, url: {action: 'show', id: @post, locale: params[:locale]} ) do |f| %>`

so it works with `update` but not with `new` because my post doesn't have an `id`

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :locale=>"en", :id=>#<Post id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, title: nil, text: nil>, :controller=>"posts"}
```

So yeah, I don't really want to use 2 forms for create and update if I can avoid doing it. Is there a good way of doing this?

edit:

here's my rake routes

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
    posts GET    /:locale/posts(.:format)          posts#index {:locale=>/en|fr/}
          POST   /:locale/posts(.:format)          posts#create {:locale=>/en|fr/}
 new_post GET    /:locale/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new {:locale=>/en|fr/}
edit_post GET    /:locale/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit {:locale=>/en|fr/}
     post GET    /:locale/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show {:locale=>/en|fr/}
          PATCH  /:locale/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update {:locale=>/en|fr/}
          PUT    /:locale/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update {:locale=>/en|fr/}
          DELETE /:locale/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy {:locale=>/en|fr/}
```

Comment: can you show the output of rake routes?  you said you get that error when trying to edit?  what's the link you click on to get to the edit page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's maybe a little extra work but still an accepted pattern to have a separate form container for the new and edit actions, such as this:

```
new.html.erb

<%= form_for(@post, url: posts_path) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'form', f: f %>
  <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
<% end %>

edit.html.erb

<%= form_for(@post, url: post_path(@post)) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'form', f: f %>
  <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
<% end %>
```

So that's one option. You render the common form fields in the `_form.html.erb` partial and do whatever's unique to your new/edit in their respective form containers.

But, if you'd really like to have just one form container file you can always do this:

```
<%= form_for(@post, url: (@post.new_record? ? posts_path : post_path(@post)) ) do |f| %>
```

Note: I'm not exactly sure how the locales gem works so I excluded that above... but if you do need to include the locale explicitly you can do that with e.g. `post_path(@post, locale: params[:locale])`. Recall that `post_path(@post)` is actually short-hand for `post_path(id: @post)`. That is, the parameters you pass into the named route are ordered the same as your route expects them if not explicitly stated.

Comment: Take into account that if for some reason you're not using `resources :entity` you may have something in your routes like `get '/entities/:entity_id/edit', :to => 'entities#edit'` so your url in the `form_for` should look like: `entity_path(entity_id: @post)`. Very nice solution thank you!

Comment: @pdobb +1 for your advice on including locale in the post_path.